# unit testing for iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing, ipad

Which is the most recommended unit test framework for iPad development?

I knew that there is a unit testing framework available inside the SDK. Is this toolset fine, or should I go for another framework?

Is unit testing is done on iPad device or just on simulator?

What pointers can you give for techniques on how to write best unit test cases for iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The included SenTestKit is quite limited and only runs in the simulator but [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) seems to be highly recommended.

Here is a list of GHUnit features

- Run tests, breakpoint and interact
  directly with the XCode Debugger.
- Run from the command line or via a
  Makefile.
- Run tests in parallel.
- Allow testing of UI components.
- Capture and display test metrics.
- Search and filter tests by keywords.
- View logging by test case.
- Show stack traces and useful
  debugging information.
- Be embeddable as a framework (using
  @rpath) for Mac OSX apps, or as a
  static library in your iPhone
  projects.